# If network providers deploy their own CDNs, then how does their CDN play with the Content providers' CDNs?

Tags: cdn, content-delivery-network

Content Delivery (Distribution) Networks help optimize the delivery speed by caching content. Network providers use CDNs to help reduce core network traffic, reduce subscriber churn and facilitate value added services. However Content providers (like Netflix) also provide their own CDNs so that their content reaches users in an efficient manner. For one thing, when a user makes a request for a video, where and how exactly would his request be redirected? Would it be sent to Content provider's OR Network provider's CDN?